# Prove: $\frac{a}{a^2+b^3+c^3}+\frac{b}{b^2+c^3+a^3}+\frac{c}{c^2+a^3+b^3}\leq \frac{1}{5abc}$ for $a+b+c=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Source: RMO 2019, question 3

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that
$$\frac{a}{a^2+b^3+c^3}+\frac{b}{b^2+c^3+a^3}+\frac{c}{c^2+a^3+b^3}\leq \frac{1}{5abc}.$$

I tried using Holder's inequality but couldn't get to the desired result.

Comment: I have solved your question. If you want to see my solution, show your Holder attempt please.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Use AM-GM to prove the following ineq: for all $a,b,c>0$,
$$\frac{a}{a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+a^2c}\leq \frac{3a+b+c}{25abc}.$$

Comment: Then what, how to get to the reasult

Comment: Add expressions of $a,b,c$,